# In Plato's Symposium, why is Diotima a woman?

Tags: plato, love

Excuse the odd title - what I mean is: Diotima is the sole woman that has her say in Plato's dialogues. There are a multitude of opportunities in which he could've let a woman speak, but it never happens *except* here. But *why* here?

If one doesn't know the context, and only knows that the Symposium is about Eros or love, it might seem reasonable: it is important for men who love women to learn about women's feelings or attitudes about love. Diotima as a woman reveals this to Socrates - something that he by being a man does not naturally understand.

But this is not the case. The context here is love between males, between an adult man and male youth - the practice of *paiderastia*.

So why did Plato make the one who teaches Socrates about the true meaning of love be a woman? I find this exceedingly strange in this male homoerotic context.

I searched for an answer and basically found three explanations:

1. To not evoke the suspicion that young Socrates was an *eromenos* (the youthful lover of an older man)
2. To make her "aloof" - if she was a man, her teachings might have been regarded with suspicion, i.e. interpreted as a seduction tactic.
3. To make her conflation of sexuality and reproduction more realistic, since it was assumed that this was the feminine perspective.

Regarding this, I say:

1. Isn't Socrates simply too old for this at the time when he met Diotima? The *eromenos* is supposed to be free of own desires. She's certainly talking to him like he's old enough to not be a boy, but to understand desire towards boys.
2. I find her own manner of presentation way too flirtatious for this (she teases Socrates, laughs at him). She doesn't sound like a solemn, unapproachable priestess.
3. Yes, that's realistic, but still it's not a strong enough reason, given that women do not occur anywhere else in the Platonic dialogues.

Comment: fun question: but did you google it? "As a woman, Diotima supposedly represents the insatiable sexual drive of women, which is a risk to the balance of a sophrosyne-practicing male majority. However, Diotima does not present an invasive threat to the masculine setting of the symposium."

Comment: there are papers titled [why is diotima a woman](https://ancphil.lsa.umich.edu/-/downloads/faculty/halperin/diotima.pdf)

Comment: @vqlk I added what I found out so far

Comment: good... i already upvoted, but thanks